# Creating a new distribution certificate without revoking old ones

Tags: iphone

Im very new to this.I want to submit  update of an app.My client forgot the password for the private key.so im going to generate a new distribution certificate and submitting to appstore.so will this create any issue?Also is it possible to create a new distribution certificate without revoking old ones.Can any one help me on this.Thanks in advance.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create new distribution certificate without revoking old one.

Solution : Create new distribution certificate and then create new provisioning profile for same app identifier.Create build and upload to app store.Good Luck!!